# Definition of "curriculum"

Tags: curriculum, terminology

In standard usage does the word "curriculum" mean

- That which ought to be taught and learned, as prescribed by authorities (i.e. teachers and textbook authors and the like); or
- That which actually *is* taught and learned in conventional practice, regardless of whether it is consistent with what authorities say ought to be taught and learned; or
- Something else?

Comment: It seems that, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum), your first meaning is the most common one.  Of course, it depends on the context where the word is used.  Also, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum#Definitions_and_interpretations): "There is no generally agreed upon definition of curriculum."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly "standard usage" means, but in educational research (and more specifically in mathematics education research) it is common to distinguish between the *intended curriculum*, the *enacted curriculum*.  It is also fairly common to refer the *attained curriculum* and the *tested curriculum*.

When used outside of a research context -- for example, by practitioners, school administrators, and policymakers -- "curriculum" (without modifiers) almost always refers to the intended curriculum.

Comment: (+1) During my teacher training, there was a great deal of discussion about the _hidden_ curriculum and what that meant. Ultimately I found this frustrating because, coming from a mathematics / computer science background, I was looking for what meaning the phrase would bring me, but those leading the discussion were looking for what meaning I could bring to the phrase.

Comment: @AndrewC : I wonder if you can explain that last remark. In mathematics, there is a de-facto curriculum that nobody talks about, whose existence is an elephant in the room, which the nominal curriculum is a naked emperor.